# Using cross product prove that if $\vec{u} \times \vec{v} = \vec{0}$ and $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ then $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$

Tags: analytic-geometry

I am asked to elaborate on the following proof:

> Let $\vec{u} \neq \vec{0}$. Prove that if $\vec{u} \times \vec{v} = \vec{0}$ and $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ then $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$.

My attempt was to say that

$$
u . v = 0 \Rightarrow (u_1, u_2, u_3) \cdot (v_1, v_2, v_3) = 0 \Rightarrow u_1 v_1 + u_2 v_2 + u_3 v_3 = 0
$$

and that

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\ 
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\ 
v_1 & v_2 & v_3
\end{vmatrix} = 0 \Rightarrow (u_2 v_3 - v_2 u_3 , u_3 v_1 - u_1 v_3 , u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1) = (0,0,0)
$$

but it seems like the wrong way to go.

How can I achieve that proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Recall that $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=0$ iff two non zero vectors are parallel, i.e. $ \vec{u}=\lambda \vec{v}.$ Conclude.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Best Regards.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: both $\sin$ and $\cos$ can't be $0$ at the same time. Note the formula for dot and cross product in terms of angles and magnitudes.

$$a\cdot b=\|a\|\|b\|\cos \theta$$

$$\|a\times b\|=\|a\|\|b\| \sin \theta $$

Comment: That's a great insight, thank you!